# Why is Rails adding 'localhost:3000/assets' to my image src?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looping over a collection of Movies in my movie like so:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to image_tag(movie.image.url), movie %>
  <%= link_to sanitize(movie.title), movie %>
</li>
```

But it's generating the following html:

```
<img alt="3382" src="http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/http//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ramen-hut/pictures/3382.jpg?1344477777">
```

It's baffled me, could anyone help on this? WHy is it adding that `http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/` url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `:` is missing after `http` in your `movie.image.url`.

Without `http://`, Rails thinks this is an asset name and adds the asset prefix.

For example:

```
<%= image_tag 'http//foo/bar.jpg' %>
<%= image_tag 'http://foo/bar.jpg' %>
```

Outputs:

```
<img alt="Bar" src="/assets/http//foo/bar.jpg" />
<img alt="Bar" src="http://foo/bar.jpg" />
```